# QTextStream(*QFile) constructor is deleted

Tags: c++, qt

I'm very new to C++ in general, and to Qt as well, thus I have a question:

I've got this code:

```
if(!logFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0, "error", logFile.errorString());
}
else {
    QTextStream result(&logFile);
    return result.readAll();
}
```

It is running fine.
However, when I try to return the QTextStream object instead of QString w/ all the text I've read from file, following error pops up:

```
/home/neko/projects/WurmLogparser/wurmlog.cpp:208: error: call to deleted constructor of 'QTextStream'
        return result;
               ^~~~~~
```

code what is causing error seen below:

```
else {
    QTextStream result(&logFile);
    return result;
    //return result.readAll();
}
```

Of course, I'm changing the related types to QTextStream appropriatelly before trying to compile second version. Please, tell me what is the problem with 2nd version of code? I construct QTextStream the same way as in the first part, but it produces strange error for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TextStream object [...] w/ all the text

The stream does not "contain" any text. It is a means of retrieving the text from a `QIODevice`, but by itself it doesn't contain the text.

Returning a string was the right thing to do in your case.

`QTextStream` is non-copyable. You can't return it by value. In most cases, it makes no sense to return such an object. If you're operating on a stream, you should pass it as a reference parameter:

```
void myFunction(QTextStream & stream) { ... }
```

If you wish to return the contents read from a file, you can return them as a string (as you did), or as raw binary data:

```
QByteArray myFunction() {
  ...
  return logFile.readAll();
}
```

You can then use a stream on the byte array:

```
void foo() {
  auto data = myFunction();
  auto stream = QTextStream(&data);
  // use the stream
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to further clarify, the copy constructor for QTextStream (and also the = operator) are both private, this is the reason that you can't copy them :o

Methods to get around that are explained well by Kuba (+1 :)